# Why does a test method with DataTestMethod decorator fail to run more than once when multiple DataRows with array arguments are specified?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, mstest

I discovered surprising behaviour of the `DataTestMethod` and `DataRow` attributes. I have implemented the following test; of course the overall context is more complex, but this is a minimal example.

```
[TestClass]
public class SomeTest
{
    [DataRow(new int[] { 1, 2 })]
    [DataRow(new int[] { 3, 4 })]
    [DataRow(new int[] { 3, 5 })]
    [DataRow(new int[] { 3, 6 })]
    [DataTestMethod]
    public void ErrorStuff(int[] array)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(array);
    }
}
```

I was expecting that during test execution, `ErrorStuff` is executed *four* times (namely for every `DataRow` provided). However, this is not the case, it is executed *once* (for the first `DataRow`, which I inspected by debugging the test).

It goes without saying that the test is not meaningful at all and there are other ways to test the desired behaviour. However, I wonder how this behaviour can be explained. As presented, it it just a toy example; however, this potentially means that some test cases are never executed and there is hardly any way to notice this.

Any ideas how the behaviour can be explained? Any help is appreciated!

However, please don't suggest technically different alternatives like usage of `DynamicData` or formulation of single test methods for the single test cases - I am aware of that, but that is not my point of interest here.

Comment: Have you tried running it with `dotnet test`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; `dotnet test` seems to execute _all_ of the test cases. But this is also not good - this means that a test case my fail in a CI pipeline, but cannot be inspected in the debugger of Visual Studio...

Comment: Then it seems to be purely VS issue. Try deleting bin/obj folders and rebuilding the solution. Also maybe some VS update/restart or machine reboot also can help.

Comment: Well yes, but even restarting the machine didn't resolve the issue. Thanks for your help so far; any further suggestions?

Comment: Maybe try updating the VS installation and if that does not help - submit VS bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Upgrade your MS Test Framework to Version 3.0+.**

You can do so via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/).  At the time of writing, the current is 3.0.4:

```
dotnet add package MSTest.TestFramework --version 3.0.4
```

After I upgraded my framework, this works as expected (4 test runs occur):

[image: test run success cmd line]

[image: test run success text explorer in visual studio]

You *may* also need to change your .csproj file to match the version number of the package:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="3.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="3.0.4" />
</ItemGroup>
```

---

This seems to of been a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/1368), and appears to have been fixed with the release of MSTest V3 according to the post.  The linked GitHub issue also goes into details of the bug:

> To give you a little more context and explain you the difference between what you see in VS and in command line. Basically, VS asks MSTest to discover tests, we then return a list and VS is using each test ID as a unique identifier for run/debug. We have a bug in 2.2.3+ of MSTest where IDs are broken for parameterized tests under some circumstances. This leads to VS mixing tests and behaving like all tests have the data of the 1st test.

Note that is seems like if you run this through a Continuous-Integration (such as Azure DevOps), it worked.  The post also explains why it worked in that case:

> As for the CI, it is using a different mechanism where it's not asking for discovery then reuse information to run tests but directly runs tests hence you don't have the issue on CI.